# Changing placeholder triggers input event in IE 10

Tags: javascript, jquery

## Basic Problem

#### `input` event --calls--> `update()` --calls--> `geoInput.receive()` --triggers--> `input` event

## Explanation

Okay I've run into a strange problem which is causing my code to loop infinitely. I have the following bit of jQuery:

```
var geoInput = $('#Geo').on('input', function() {
  _this._controller.update({
    geo: this.value
  });
}).get(0);
```

As you can see it's just a basic event listener and it's calling an update function in my controller. At the end of the update function is a method which broadcasts for the `geoInput` field to update. This is handled by the following:

```
geoInput.receive = function(formState) {
  this.value = formState.geo;
  this.placeholder = _this._placeholders.geo;
}
```

For some reason

```
this.placeholder = _this._placeholders.geo;
```

is triggering the `input` event on that field. You can see how this can be problematic as this creates an infinite loop. I'm sure this is what's happening because when I `return` before that line the loop doesn't occur. Also, if I change to say, a `keyup` event, the loop also doesn't occur.

## Question

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

## I've tried!

I've looked at this for hours and done quite a few searches to no avail. This code works as expected in Chrome and FF.

Comment: Can you create a http://www.jsfiddle.net for this?

Comment: can a simple check prevent the infinite loop? `if (this.placeholder !== _this._placeholders.geo) { this.placeholder = _this._placeholders.geo; }

Comment: I'm working on the fiddle now!

Comment: Well I'm still working on the fiddle. The problem is that it's part of a larger project and I'm trying to keep it as minimal as possible so I could be leaving something out. Doing the if statement won't work because this is happening regardless of whether the placeholder is set or not. The mere act of setting the placeholder is messing it up

Answer (score 1):

The funny thing is that the INPUT event occurs if you just add an item to the INPUT attributes placheholder or value other than the Latin alphabet.
It's problem IE10 and IE11

```
var $input = $('<input type="text" placeholder="Бубу"/>');
//or
var $input = $('<input type="text" value="世界へようこそ"/>');
$input.on('input',function(){
    alert('input even occur');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your fiddle, I think you can fix the issue with this code:

```
var previousGeoInput = '';
var geoInput = $('#Geo').on('input', function() {
  if (previousGeoInput === this.value) {
    return;
  }
  previousGeoInput = this.value;
  _this._controller.update({
    geo: this.value
  });
}).get(0);
```

Answer (score -1):

Check the event keycode/charcode if it's 0 then it's IE being stupid and you can just cancel the event.

Comment: `input` events don't have any codes associated with them, they just signal that input has been submitted to the element.