# attrs.$set in scope.$watch function keeps directive busy

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a contact validation directive at plunker below ... 
http://plnkr.co/edit/9kgZgW?p=info

```
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  link: function(scope, elem, attrs, controller) {
    var fieldValue;
    var checker = function() {

      // Get the value of the field type
      var dateType = elem.inheritedData("$formController")[attrs.formFieldValidate];
      var dataTypeValue = dateType.$viewValue;

      // get the field value to be validated against the field type
      fieldValue = scope.$eval(attrs.ngModel);

      switch (dataTypeValue) {
        case "Email":
          attrs.$set('placeholder', 'username@example.com');
          return (fieldValue && VALID_EMAIL.test(fieldValue)) ? true : false;
        case "Phone":
          attrs.$set('placeholder', '1234567890 | 123 456 7890 | (123) 456-7890 | 123-456-7890');
          return (fieldValue && VALID_PHONE.test(fieldValue)) ? true : false;
        case "IM":
          attrs.$set('placeholder', 'username@example.com');
          return (fieldValue && VALID_IM.test(fieldValue)) ? true : false;
        default:
          attrs.$set('placeholder', 'Details');
          return false;
      }
    };
    scope.$watch(checker, function(valid) {
      scope.validField = valid;
      return valid ? fieldValue : undefined;
    });
  }
};
```

The code works perfectly except IE10 and IE11 where the checker function run infinite time. Primary investigation shows the attrs.$set in default switch case keeps it running. The result is browser being frozen.

Could you point out, how I can make scope.$watch work with attrs.$set in a directive?

Please note the issue is in IE10 and IE11 only.

Comment: Try with like: var unwatch = scope.$watch and inside the $watch block when tou have the job done call unwatch()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be caused by the fact that IE fires `input` event when you set `placeholder` value.

You can find more details about this weird IE behaviour in this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2614).

As a work around you could change your checker to to only set new `placeholder` attribute when it value needs update:

```
var newPlaceholder = attrs.placeholder;
switch (dataTypeValue) {
    case "Email":
      newPlaceholder = 'username@example.com';
      result = (fieldValue && VALID_EMAIL.test(fieldValue)) ? true : false;
    case "Phone":
      newPlaceholder = '1234567890 | 123 456 7890 | (123) 456-7890 | 123-456-7890';
      result = (fieldValue && VALID_PHONE.test(fieldValue)) ? true : false;
    case "IM":
      newPlaceholder = 'username@example.com';
      result =  (fieldValue && VALID_IM.test(fieldValue)) ? true : false;
    default:
      newPlaceholder =  'Details';
      result = false;
}
if(newPlaceholder !== attrs.placeholder){
    attrs.$set('placeholder', newPlaceholder);
}
return result;
```

There seems to be a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389732/changing-placeholder-triggers-input-event-in-ie-10).

*As a side node you probably shouldn't update anything inside `watch` expression function. It would make much more sense to have a separate watch function on `dataTypeValue` that would update `placeholderText` property on `$scope` and have `placeholder` attribute bound through html `<input type="text" ng-model="inputText" placeholder="{{placeholderText}}" />`*

Comment: Hi @miensol, thanks for pointing the IE issue and solution followed. Yes this did the trick. I second your side note. Ideally it should have been written that way only. Thanks once again.